# Guarantors and Moshiach

Tags: commentaries, messiah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In Be-Ikvei HaKetuvim ([בעקבי הכתובים](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/628634/p/66/t/0.146949229743718271234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)) by Rav Yaakov Edelstein, Rav Edelstein quotes [Yeshayahu 53:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.53.4?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi) where it says:

> But in truth he has borne our sicknesses and endured our pains; yet we did esteem him stricken, smitten of G-d, and afflicted.

Rav Edelstein gives multiple explanations on this pasuk. One of those is that sometimes, suffering comes upon a tzaddik, in order to teach mankind how to serve G-d. A different explanation is that although the tzaddik is blameless, he is suffering because of our sins, due to the fact that he serves as a guarantor.

**The question is: What does Rav Edelstein explain on the concept of "the tzaddik being a guarantor and thus suffering because of sins of other people"?**

This question is a follow-up from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/129063/27180). However, in that question, it deals with another subject, this question however, deals with the subject of "the tzaddik and his role as a guarantor"

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128895/moshiach-bearing-the-sickness-of-bnei-yisrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rb Edelstein does not say that afflictions come on the *tzaddik* because of *arvus* (the notion of being a guarantor).

He says that the affliction that was fitting to befall the generation may befall the *tzaddik* since he is strong enough to bear the afflictions on behalf of the generation.

[image]

Comment: As I understand, the tzaddik might suffer because he serves as a guarantor.

Comment: @Shmuel He does not mention the word guarantor so this would be a matter of interpretation. The simple meaning of what he says appears to be more along the lines of "someone has to pay the bill".